# How to import code coverage into Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure-pipelines, code-coverage, vstest

In Azure Devops Pipeline build, I enabled Code Coverage for the VSTest task, and it provided the code coverage artifact on the build run.

I can download that file but where can I load it into Visual Studio for analysis?

Of note, I have VS 2019 Professional, not Enterprise.

Comment: Hi enorl76,  any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the above, I think Visual Studio Enterprise is necessary for using code coverage.